# is there a performance hit for using ps.setObject instead of type specific methods for SQL prepared statements?

Tags: java, sql

I have an application where I'm using ps.set... to set the parameters for a prepared statement. I have had a hard time getting the correct of calls for storing java Date objects where I have both a time and date (and don't mention Calendar in this whole mess). What I have found is that if I use a java.util.Date with ps.setObject, it does the right thing and is much less confusing. In fact, I have found that if I want to set an int or String or BigDecimal, setObject does the right thing for them as well. So, my questions are: is this a bad practice (if so, is it a theoretical bad thing or a practical bad thing)  and is there a significant performance hit for doing it this way?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the driver implementation, some drivers wrap all their set methods around `setObject` so `setObject` does less work. However I would normally expect `setDate` to do less work than `setObject`.

However if `setObject` is doing what you want then use it. If you have performance issues with databases then swapping `setObject` with `setDate` will only fix them if the type was an issue.

For instance recently I had a problem with the database wanting me to use setDate instead of setTimestamp. This made a `200ms` query take `250 seconds` to complete. Swapping `setObject` for `setDate` will add less than 1ms to your query.

Where `setDate` has a definite benefit over `setObject`. Is `readability` the code is saying I need a `Date` here rather than saying anything is good.